# Can't import module from local folder? "No module named"

Tags: python, python-import

I don't find the mistake in the code nor in the call when trying an import test.

My directory structure is the following: (from `/home/user1/python_test/`)

```
main.py
Aux/lib1.py
Aux/__init__.py
```

main.py:

```
from Aux.lib1 import fun_A

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun_A()
    print("all done")
```

Aux/lib1.py:

```
def fun_A():
    print("A function called")
```

I'm executing from terminal (`python main.py` from directory where main.py is), maybe is there a  need to set pythonpath? I don't recall the need before, I've made some python programs like these some time ago (2/3 years)

I have also tried `from .Aux.lib1 import fun_A` instead of `from Aux.lib1 import fun_A` but nothing works. The error is:

```
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Aux.lib1 import fun_A
ImportError: No module named Aux.lib1
```

Comment: Use:`os.getcwd()` This will show you what is the current directory you are running this code. and use `os.chdir('/home/user1/python_test/')`  To change it

Comment: It is the same result: `os.getcwd()` outputs `/home/user1/python_test/`

Comment: The example works perfectly fine on my machine. There must be something else with your Python environment

Comment: uhm, and what could I search to know the problem? It is strange for me too, usually it works without error.

Answer (score 2):

Create a blank file with name `__init__.py` under the folder Aux. Without this file a directory can not be a module.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't mention it, but I also have that file inside `Aux/`

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, It was a super silly mistake. I'm so used to execute inside a virtual environment that I was using python2 by mistake using `python main.py`. Executing `python3 main.py` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

python or python3 was not working for me. I have solved the problem by putting this line `sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())` after `importing os`.